# Skype for Business UCMA SDK

Tags: .net, lync, skype-for-business, ucma, ucma2.0

I want to develop a REST service using UCMA 4.0 SDK. My service will achieve the communication between my company's program and our customer's Skype for Business on-premise server.
To configure my application server as a trusted server, I need to execute PowerShell command which has a local domain.
In the configuration process do I need absolutely use Active Directory domain? Or can I use IP?

ps: This will be my very first time using .NET and UCMA SDK even Windows Server. If anyone does know about this subject please help me :D And also, I do need some advice.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you know that there is already a REST based API called [UCWA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype-sdk/ucwa/unifiedcommunicationswebapi2_0)?
  Depending on what you are trying to do that may be enough.

UCMA allows you to create two main types of applications.

- User Applications
- Trusted Server Applications

[User Applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lync/ucma-sdk/client-platforms) can run anyway, if all you need is a user endpoint within Skype For Business that this is the best way to go.  If all you need is a this then UCWA will most likely provide all you need as well.  The requirement of a user application is that you need the users password to use it.  Basically you are logging in as that user endpoint to do all your work.

[Trusted Server Applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lync/ucma-sdk/server-platforms) are applications that can run "special" sip endpoints called [trusted application endpoints and user endpoints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lync/ucma-sdk/user-endpoints-and-application-endpoints).  The setup for a trusted application is involved.  Basically the trusted application can only run on a trusted application pool (basically pre-trusted computer(s)) and requires very specific certificate setup.  Read the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lync/ucma-sdk/activating-a-ucma-4-0-trusted-application) very carefully and follow it if you need to go down this road.  On setting up a trusted server application / application pool customer there is a setup around "[auto-provisioned](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lync/ucma-sdk/activating-an-auto-provisioned-application)" and "[manually provisioned](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lync/ucma-sdk/activating-a-manually-provisioned-application)" setups.  I would recommend the manually provisioned setup as the computer setup requirements are a lot easier, the down side is that you will require more code to setup your application.  The auto-provisioned is easier for coding but is very over the top on the computer setup requirements.  You will most likely require your IT persons help in setting up the Lync / Skype for Business side as parts of the setup require AD administrator requirements.

The below answers are for the trusted application setup only.

> In the configuration process do I need absolutely use Active Directory domain?

Not sure what you mean, if you mean the Trusted Application Pool computer, then yes/no.  You don't have to be a member of the AD, BUT you will find the whole process easier if it is.  There are specific certificate requirements which are tied to the pool name and computer name(s) with specific certificate requirement setups for the computer / trusted application to be allowed to run within Lync.

> Or can I use IP?

No.  Everything in Lync is controlled via certificates which is tied to computer names specified in the Lync setup.

Comment: Hello Shane, I am really grateful that you replied to my question. In the beginning, I also thought that UCWA is more appropriate for my basic web service. What I am trying to do is receive all messages and sender ids for a specific Lync User than send this information, and listen to responses from my company's program. But I realize that UCWA is an old API, as an example, it takes 16 steps to receive an instant message through UCWA. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/skype-sdk/ucwa/receiveanim I don't want to build a fragile system. Am I misunderstood UCWA? Thanks again for your reply.

Comment: All the Lync/S4B API's have been deprecated...  You can do whatever is easiest for you.  UCWA / User UCMA Applications require the users password, so if you are dealing with just one user then choose between either of these.  If you want to do this for multiple users at the same time, then a trusted application is a better way.